# SQL not creating tables (refresh and restart didn't help)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

**Context**

I am trying to create multiple tables with SQL Commands. After I have executed the `Create` commands, I am not getting a visual feedback in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. In other words: I don't see any table entries in my Database. When I create a Database in the same SQL file, it gets created without problems.

**SQL Statements**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS CheckSum;
CREATE DATABASE CheckSum;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Translation;
CREATE TABLE Translation (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    LanguageName varchar(50),

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NationalBank;
CREATE TABLE NationalBank (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Abbreviation varchar(1),
    NationalBankName varchar(100),
    CountryAbbreviation varchar(1),

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Country;
CREATE TABLE Country (
    CountryID int NOT NULL,
    LanguageID int,
    CountryName varchar(100),
    Abbreviation varchar(1),

    PRIMARY KEY (CountryID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Code;
CREATE TABLE Code (
    Code int NOT NULL,
    LanguageID int,
    CodeMessage varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (Code, LanguageID)
);


INSERT INTO Translation (LanguageName) VALUES ('Deutsch');
INSERT INTO Translation (LanguageName) VALUES ('English');


INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (1, 1, 'Großbritannien', 'j');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (2, 1, 'Österreich', 'n');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (3, 1, 'Irland', 't');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (4, 1, 'Deutschland', 'x');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (5, 1, 'Schweden', 'k');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (6, 1, 'Niederlande', 'p');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (7, 1, 'Frankreich', 'u');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (CountryID, LanguageID, CountryName, Abbreviation) VALUES (8, 1, 'Griechenland', 'y');
/* ... */
```

[image: MSSMS not showing the tables]

**Additional Information**

- When i remove the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and rerun it. I get an error saying `There is already an object named 'Translation' in the database.`
- Refreshing and restarting didn't help. I am having this problem for about two weeks now.
- I am trying to get these tables into C# Entity Framework but the GUI there doesn't show me the tables either.
- Creating the tables with the MSSMS GUI works.

I would greatly appreciate a piece of advice on how to solve this one. I certainly don't have much experience working with SQL :)

Comment: If you are creating a database, you are not immediately connected to it. So you are probably creating those tables in `master` (or whatever database you were connected to). Alter your script with `USE CheckSum` after database creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I right-clicked on the database and chose `New Query`. That way it automatically connected to the database I wanted. It's working now! Edit: The `USE` works equally well

Comment: There's also a drop down up on the toolbar to select the database that a query runs within. You're not limited to only opening the query window from the database.